# Trying to divide API data among multiple pages in React.js using Axios

Tags: reactjs, api, for-loop, axios, get

I have been wrestling with this for a couple days.

The goal is to get the API data and divide it into different arrays or groups of data. I have different pages that will display different data based on the context of the titles in the API. I realize I could use a different API request per page which, I think I could figure out but I was trying to minimize the number of requests to the API. I really don't know the best way forward.

I am using React.js and Axios.

Sorry for the noob question. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: `https://obscure-basin-88823.herokuapp.com/https://api.printify.com/v1/shops/2861059/products.json`
})
/*2861059*/
const options = {
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer SECRET API KEY'}
};

export default class App extends Component {
  
  state = {
    shirts: [],
    houstonshirts: [],
  }

  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    /*this.renderHoustonShirts = this.renderHoustonShirts.bind(this);*/
    this.gethoustonshirts = this.gethoustonshirts.bind(this);
  }

  gethoustonshirts = async () => {
    let houArray
    let data
    api.get('/', options).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
      this.setState({ shirts: res.data.data })
    })
      data = this.state.shirts
      houArray = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].title.includes("Astros")){
        houArray.push(data[i]);
        this.setState({houstonshirts: houArray})
        console.log("houstonshirts = " + houArray)
        } 
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.gethoustonshirts();
}


render() {
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(
      this.state.houstonshirts 
    );
  }, 1000);
  return ( ...so on and so forth
```

Comment: your information is vague. What is the response of "data = this.state.shirts" ? I need to see its structure

Answer (score 0):

In your gethoustonshirts method use the below code.

```
 api.get("/", options).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
    this.setState({
      shirts: res.data.data,
      houstonshirts: res.data.data.filter(_shirt => _shirt.title.includes("Astros"))
     });
 });
```

Comment: You are my new favorite person.

It seems simple and obvious now that I see it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.